# What do ELU/ELL/OP stand for?

Tags: discussion

I'd very much appreciate if somebody could tell me what the following acronyms stand for:

a) **ELU**

b) **ELL**

c) **OP**

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/3055 about VtC

Comment: Also related about OP : http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/2902/ (I'm just linking these questions together in case we decide to make a proper glossary).

Answer (score 4):

- SE = Stack Exchange (this family of sites)
- ELL = English Language
  Learners, an SE site dedicated to helping learners of
  English
- ELU = English Language & Usage, a sister site for linguists
  and etymologists
- OP = Original Poster, a generic way to refer to the individual who asked a question.  Sometimes it can mean Original Post (See [The Urban Dictionary](http://op.urbanup.com/5393886), and a [WOW forum](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6572267711#2)).

Comment: and sometimes 'Original Post'...

Comment: @AlanC - Yes, if it refers to the post itself rather than the author. Good point.

Comment: I'm starting to think we should have a variation of SE glossary here.

Comment: PhMgBr.- Let me get familiar with the glossary you have at present before changing it, please!

Comment: @lalynacar - I think PhMgBr is saying that we could add some more terms in addition to these and make this question even more useful to future visitors.

Comment: @Lal I was referring to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms). I was implying we might need a similar post on meta.ELL for reference.

Comment: @PhMgBr, J.R., lalynacar [A bit like this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7914/elu-glossaries)?

Comment: @Arau yep, but with a bit of extra conclusion. :P